# How do I detect visitor's real ip from CloudFlare?

Tags: php, cloudflare

I use cloudflare for my website and I am wondering why my clients IP changing every time I use this script.

In Google my IP is `5.250.13.100` also in other sites like `whatismyip` I have same.

But when I use this script in my site(with cloudflare) every time I load this script its give me different IP in same range?

```
<? 
echo $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]; 
?>
```

IP range is: 173.245.*.*  - 188.114.*.*

[By looking in CloudFlare IP ranges I found this range is from CloudFlar!](http://cloudflare.com/ips)

- So how can I detect in my website my visitor's real IP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
$realip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'];
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

various solutions from [cloudflare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/sections/200038166-How-do-I-restore-original-visitor-IP-to-my-server-logs-)

From CloudFlare :

> To restore the original visitor IP addresses to log files and web
>   applications running on Apache httpd web servers, you will need to
>   install mod_cloudflare